# Double tapping links in webview

Tags: hyperlink, webview

I have problem with people double clicking links in my WebView. Sometimes the scripts are done a few times if a person taps the link a couple times.

I tried to disable the WebView and set it unclickable in the override of url loading but it doesn't seem to work, every now and then someone still manages to get a double tap.

Anyone have any ideas how to implement a loading screen that would stop people from tapping the link two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, to double click something, first the click event will trigger 2 times, I will make something like this:

```
    var isClicked = false;

    $("a").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (!isClicked){
               isClicked = true;
               // Do something
          }
     });
```

Just set the isClicked and update it to false when the process ends.